# codemod from ForInStatement to ForStatement

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, jscodeshift

I have a codemod where I want to transform

```
for (var key in foo){}
```

into

```
for (var keys = 0; key < foo; key++){}
```

I managed this far:

```
return j(file.source)
    .find(j.ForInStatement)
    .replaceWith(p => {

        var prop = p.node.left.declarations[0].id;

        var v = [j.variableDeclarator(prop, null)];
        var varDec = j.variableDeclaration('var', v);
        var binary = j.binaryExpression('<', prop, j.identifier('foo'));
        var uE = j.updateExpression('++', prop, false);
        var block = j.blockStatement([]);

        var forIn = j.forStatement(varDec, binary, uE, block);
        return forIn;
    })
    .toSource();
```

and [that brought me this far](https://astexplorer.net/#/I8VPim4PQZ):

```
for (var key; key < foo; key++)
  {}
```

I'm still a bit lost creating things from scratch...

**Question:**

- Am I doing this correct? feels quite verbose, but maybe it is the way to go.
- How to finish? I am missing for example `foo.length`...

**PS:** [Felix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling), if you are reading this, do point me where can I send pull requests to improve the docs! I am happy to help with that while I trying to learn this API. Oh, and Felix, what a nice tool you guys made!

Comment: I'll answer tomorrow... doing things explicitly is verbose, but sometimes there is no way around it. We can simplify some things here though. I'm glad you like it :) someone started https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift/wiki/jscodeshift-Documentation, no PR necessary! But yeah, I should invest some time documentation, sorry for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating AST nodes directly is indeed verbose. However, jscodeshift exports some helper "methods" that allow you to generate AST nodes from a string and let you interpolate existing AST nodes (tagged templates ftw!).

Your above example could be simplified to:

```
  return j(file.source)
    .find(j.ForInStatement)
    .replaceWith(p => {
      var prop = p.node.left.declarations[0].id;
      return statement`for (var ${prop} = 0; ${prop} < foo.length; ${prop}++) ${p.node.body}`;
    })
    .toSource();
```

[DEMO](https://astexplorer.net/#/ucQGRA8Rtt/1)

Note though that those template methods (`expression`, `statement`, `statements`) have their limitations (you can only interpolate AST nodes where you can put an identifier).

---

If you wanted to create `foo.length` manually, you would have to create a `MemberExpression`:

[image]

```
j.memberExpression(
  prop,
  j.identifier('length')
);
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! Added a variation to get the `foo` variable from the former node like https://astexplorer.net/#/ucQGRA8Rtt/2 Wow, what a nice feature that interpolation pssobility! (tagged templates ftw indeed!). I managed to [fight the verbose batle and win](https://astexplorer.net/#/ZkmUj8qx84), next time I'll with tagged template! Thank you again.

Comment: Oops, yeah, I handled `foo` incorrectly. Sorry about that!